# CSS custom variant for label not working in Android emulator

Tags: android, css, label

I applied a stylesheet in my tabris application with a custom variant for a label.

1. Registered stylesheet in the configuration of the application:
   application.addStyleSheet( "org.eclipse.rap.rwt.theme.Default", "/theme/tourfinder.css" );
2. Added a custom variant for a label
   titleLabel.setData( RWT.CUSTOM_VARIANT, "mylabel" );
3. Added css resource with content:
   Label.mylabel {
     color: blue;
     font: 32px Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
   }

In the browser the label is rendered well (blue color and big font), but when I use the android emulator, the custom variant for the label is not applied.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Tabris the look of widgets is defined by the platform running the app. That means on Android a button looks like an Android button while the theming is only used to configure dimensions but the colors etc can not be changed.